# Rewrite URL if controller is not existing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

Rewrite URL if user tried to access any non existing controller.

Ex:- If user tried to access `http://example.com/project/anyvalue` . In my program there is no controller with name 'anyvalue'. In this situation I want to redirect to

```
http://example.com/project/profile/anyvalue
```

How is this possible using routing in codeigniter?

Comment: Try using 'URI Routing' in this user guide [CI URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: can i set route like this $route['project/^(?!other|controllers).*'] = 'project/profile/$1';

Answer (score 1):

Use default route to redirect requests to some particular page if controller is missing

You can find routes location in

/application/admin/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

Also use following in case of page not found

```
$route['404_override'] = 'default_page';
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's only for the root of the document and not for missing controllers.

Comment: if user tried to access http://example.com/project/anyvalue then i need to redirect to http://example.com/project/profile/anyvalue . this is the project profile page. I don't need redirect to default controller. thank you for the support.

Comment: Updated ans to cover all possibilities.. Thanks for your input.. @RyanMcDonough

Answer (score 1):

1. Add routes to all existing controllers under "/project/..."
2. Add a route that will match any paths under "/project"

Example:

```
/* Currently available controllers under "/project/" */
$route['project/profile'] = "project/profile";
$route['project/add'] = "project/add";
$route['project/edit'] = "project/edit";

/* Catch all others under "/project/" */
$route['project/(:any)'] = "project/profile/$1";

/* if controller class name is Profile and function name is index */
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/profile/index/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Vanity URLs, you can find a guide for performing this in code igniter here:

http://philpalmieri.com/2010/04/personalized-user-vanity-urls-in-codeigniter/

Essentially you're adding this to your routes file:

```
$handle = opendir(APPPATH."/modules");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if(is_dir(APPPATH."/modules/".$file)){
    $route[$file] = $file;
    $route[$file."/(.*)"] = $file."/$1";
  }
}

/*Your custom routes here*/

/*Wrap up, anything that isnt accounted for pushes to the alias check*/
$route['([a-z\-_\/]+)'] = "aliases/check/$1";
```